# ZFS Zpool import changed disk identifier

Tags: filesystems, zfs

I created a new ZPool on my disk with the `zpool create` command.

Shortly after that, I read that you should specify the pool-disks by `/dev/disk/by-id/` and not by the identificator `/dev/sda` for example.
I didn't do this on my pool, and now I have a problem:

Because of a new disk, all identifiers changed for the existing disks.

The pool was on `/dev/sdb`, now is this disk localized on `/dev/sdc`.

Zfs doesn't realizes this, and it tries to access the existing pool at `/dev/sdb`, but it isn't there.

through searching the web, I found a possibility to import unmounted zpools: `zpool import`.

But if I want to import the existing, unavailable pool with `zpool import dte` ("dte" was the name of the pool), I get the following error:

```
ms@linuxServer:/# sudo zpool import dte
cannot import 'dte': pool may be in use from other system
use '-f' to import anyway
```

If I try with the `-f` option, I get the following error:

```
ms@linuxServer:/# sudo zpool import dte -f
cannot import 'dte': one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

So it really tries to mount `/dev/sdb`, but this is used.

If I just use `zpool import` it shows me the following:

```
ms@linuxServer:/# sudo zpool import
   pool: dte
     id: 12561099924127384920
  state: FAULTED
 status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
        The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using
        the '-f' flag.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E
 config:

        dte                     FAULTED  corrupted data
          ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_X3N87RPGS  UNAVAIL  corrupted data
```

Does anyone know, how I can tell the zpool-command, that the pool "dte" is located at /dev/sdc and not at /dev/sdb?

I haven't found any possible, usable solution yet.
Just this one, which didn't really help:

[Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zfs-fuse/f4IobTSk_fo)

[whirlpool.net](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1588076)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your zpool import command string should be: `sudo zpool import -f dte`

Following that, you should be able to `zpool clear`.

Comment: You were right. But:
The big problem was, that I hadn't the same Harddisk-Configuration as when I made the pool.

Answer (score 0):

**Symlinking** worked for me which allow at least to "clear" the pool but it his so frustrating not knowing how to re-attribute devices path! All i found so far is never use `/dev/*` identifiers for drives when intend to sue with ZFS, use what you can easily edit in `/fstab`.

Answer (score -1):

why not symlinking ?
ln -s /dev/sdb /dev/sdc

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if that would have worked. It might be worth a try, but I don't have the methods to do so right now.

But thank you for your answer. Maybe it was as simple as this and I didn't think of it... ;)